# How to get the index of element from body tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexing

As we know if we have a HTML code like this:

```
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="item">item 1</div>
        <div class="item">item 2</div>
        <div class="item">item 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent">
        <div class="item">item 4</div>
        <div class="item">item 5</div>
        <div class="item">item 6</div>
        <div class="item">item 7</div>
    </div>

<div class="item">item 8</div>
<div class="item">item 9</div>
</body>
```

So I'm trying to do like this. When we click on one of item, how we can know the index of this element from body tag. I know that when we use index() function if we click:

- "item 8" it will return 2,
- "item 9" will return 3,
- "item 7" will return 4,

So how can we know exactly the index of "item" from root (I mean body tag)? So when we click on "item 8" it will return 7 instead of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no proper way to do that, and you should properly reconsider putting the index in the element, for instance:

```
<div class="item" data-index=8>item 8</div>
```

And then in the onclick event handler, you can access this index by:

$(event.currentTarget).data("index")

That being said, here is a proposal to solve your direct problem (but I repeat myself: unless you simplified the question to great extent, there is probably something wrong with the approach...)

```
$(function(){
    $(".item").on("click", function(event){
        var clickedIndex;
        var clickedItem = $(event.currentTarget)[0];
        $(".item").each(function(index, item){
          if(item == clickedItem)
            clickedIndex = index;             
        });
        //Put the result somewhere...
        $("#show-index").html(clickedIndex);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/z38pZ/1)

Edit: all the other proposed solutions are much better :) I didn't know .index() could take a selector. But my point stays the same, basing anything on the index of a element in the DOM, disregarding the structure around it, is a bit fishy... from experience, when I had to do that, it was a problem I could have solved in a cleaner way with Ids or other information...

Answer (score 3):

Pass the selector to the `index()` method:

```
$(this).index('.item')
```

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
> integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
> object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
> element is not found, .index() will return -1.

#### [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXvVr/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try [index(Selector)](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-selector)

> A selector representing a jQuery collection in which to look for an element.

```
$(this).index('.item');
```

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AVJR3/)</kbd>

> Note:- index starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.item').each(function() {
           console.log($(this).index() + " - " + $(this).html());
     });     
});
```